# How to prebuffer VideoView A while another VideoView B is playing - Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, buffering

I am interested in being able to "prebuffer" VideoView **A** while VideoView **B** is playing. Is this possible?

- I have two instances of a VideoView.
- Only one VideoView will be displayed at a given time, taking up the entire screen of the phone.
- The purpose is to reduce the "black screen" when switching from VideoView A and VideoView B.
- The app plays a list of videos one after another.

**Added Below Code on Jan 19, 2015**

The code below grabs a reference to each Player's MediaPlayer. When MediaPlayer A begins rendering, MediaPlayer B will call stop(), release(), setDataSource(url), prepareAsync(). When MediaPlayer A completes, Media Player B will call start().

```
public class PrebufferingActivity extends Activity {
    private VideoView player1;
    private VideoView player2;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;
    public static final String URL_1 = "sample1.mp4";
    public static final String URL_2 = "sample2.mp4";

    public boolean FIRST_TIME = true;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prebuffering);

        player1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer1);
        player2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer2);

        player1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        });

        player2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
             }
        });
        player1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)            {
                mediaPlayer2.start();

                // Toggle visibility. Player1 is completed. Hide Player1. Show Player2.
                player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                player1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        player1.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
            {
                if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)
                {
                    mediaPlayer2.stop();
                    mediaPlayer2.release();

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(URL_2);
                        mediaPlayer2.prepareAsync();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        player1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)          {
                mediaPlayer1 = mp;

                if(FIRST_TIME == true) {
                    mediaPlayer1.start();
                    player1.requestFocus();
                    FIRST_TIME = false;
                }
            }
        });

        player2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)            {
                mediaPlayer1.start();
                player1.requestFocus();

                // Toggle visibility. Player2 is completed. Hide Player2. Show Player1.
                player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                player2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        player2.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
            {
                if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)
                {
                    // Prepare Player 2
                    mediaPlayer1.stop();
                    mediaPlayer1.release();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(PrebufferingActivity.URL_1);
                        mediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        player2.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer2 = mp;
            }
        });

        // Player 1
        player1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        player1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL_1));

        // Player 2
        player2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        player2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL_2));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `MediaPlayer` to handle the playback of your videos within your `VideoView`, you can use the `prepareAsync()` method to achive this. The `prepareAsync()` method essentially performs the same function as `prepare()`, which is used to buffer and prepare a video, except it can be done asynchronously in the background.

**EDIT**

I did something similiar but I actually used `SurfaceView`. To handle another stream, simply create another instance of `MediaPlayer`. The following example will create two instances of `MediaPlayer` and buffer the first video. After the first video is prepared, the second video will be asynchronously buffered. The first `MediaPlayer` is then bound to the `SurfaceView` and the first video is started. When the first video is finished playing, the corresponding instance of `MediaPlayer` is released, the secondary instance is attached, and the second video is automatically started. The following example code has been tested and works fine:

```
public class StreamingActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{

    MediaPlayer     mediaPlayerPrimary;
    MediaPlayer     mediaPlayerSecondary;
    SurfaceHolder   surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceView     surfaceView;
    String          videoSourcePrimary = "videoSourcePrimaryURL";
    String          videoSourceSecondary = "videoSourceSecondaryURL";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.streaming_activity_layout);
        /** Create SurfaceView */
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            /** Create MediaPlayer(s) */
            mediaPlayerPrimary = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayerSecondary = new MediaPlayer();
            /** Attach primary MediaPlayer to SurfaceView */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            /** Set sources */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.setDataSource(videoSourcePrimary);
            mediaPlayerSecondary.setDataSource(videoSourceSecondary);
            /** Prepare MediaPlayer(s) */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.prepare();
            mediaPlayerSecondary.prepareAsync();
            /** Set listeners */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayerPrimary.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayerSecondary.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayerSecondary.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            /** Set audio stream type */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayerSecondary.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        if (mp == mediaPlayerPrimary)
        {
            /** First video ready, start playback */
            mediaPlayerPrimary.start();
        }
        else if (mp == mediaPlayerSecondary)
        {
            /** Second video is ready */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        /** First video is completed, start second video */
        mediaPlayerPrimary.release();
        mediaPlayerSecondary.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayerSecondary.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.streaming_activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Willis. By any chance, do you know how to get the MediaPlayer object from the VideoView object? Can't seem to find something like getMediaPlayer()...

Comment: Also, lets say I want to change the URL to VideoView A before calling prepareAsync() on its' MediaPlayer object. Should I do the following: videoViewA.stopPlayback(); videoViewA.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));   videoViewA.getMediaPlayer().prepareAsync();

Comment: Hi Willis, is it possible to display the default Video Playback Controls (FF/RW/Play/Pause/Stop) w/ buffer indicator using this view? I'm interseted in a way to confirm that the succeeding video has been prebufferred

Comment: You can confirm that the succeeding video has been prebuffered whenever `onPrepared()` is called for the second time (`mp == mediaPlayerSecondary`).

Comment: Thanks Willis. I added some code to the original post. I followed your advice using the MediaPlayer reference and calling release(), setDataSource(), prepareAsync(), start(). However, the code seems to crash when the view is touched. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code. Does my code appear to prebuffer correctly? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your code is crashing when you touch the screen because you have not set up an `OnTouchListener` to handle touch events

Comment: Hi Willis, I added an onTouch listener for both players now but seems I am getting IllegalStateException when one of the MediaPlayer's executes  start()

Comment: Does it look like the order of stop(), release(), setDataSource(url), prepareAsync(), start() is incorrect?